# Problema con ñ's y tildes en función barplot con BERT y Excel

Tags: r

soy nuevo con R y me topé con un problema al momento de usar BERT con Excel. Resulta que estoy añadiendo funciones a Excel para personalizar reportes de resultados en el trabajo, trabajo en el sector educativo, y al momento de intentar hacer un barplot me doy cuenta que la ñ en Español y la tilde en Matemáticas no aparecen; leí en algunos foros pero no encontré algo que me sirviera para el caso de una función.
Agradezco de antemano, dejo aquí el código que uso.

```
graph.barplot <- function(data, main="Promedio general", xlabel="Materias", ylabel="Promedio"){

  BERT.graphics.device(cell=T);

  
  x <- unlist( as.numeric( data ));

  barplot( x, xlab=xlabel, legend=c("Español","Matemáticas","Ciencias","Arte"), ylab=ylabel, main=main, col="royalblue", family = "Calibri", border="NA", font.main=2);

  
  dev.off();

  
  T
}
```

'''

Answer (score 2):

### Disculpen que me responda solo, creo haber encontrado la solución (y tal vez alguien lo necesite).-

Edité el código (creo que así se dice) y en lugar de poner los nombres como strings les di su valor a las variables a y b y acto seguido estas variables las convertí a UTF-8. El resultado de la parte modificada fue el siguiente:

```
  a <- "Español"
  b <- "Matemáticas"
  Encoding(a) <- "UTF-8"
  Encoding(b) <- "UTF-8"

  barplot( x, xlab=xlabel, legend=c(a,b,"Ciencias","Arte"), ylab=ylabel, main=main, col="royalblue", family = "Calibri", border="NA", font.main=2);
```

Comment: Hola Misahel, es totalmente válido que autorespondas una pregunta, no tienes que pedir disculpas. Saludos